# Webpack - installing multiple loaders at once

Tags: webpack

I'm quite new to webpack and I find it exhausting to have to reinstall every useful loaders for each project I start. Isn't there a way to install multiple loaders at once, or to speed up the process of setting up a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Its possible

1) Copy **package.json** file from previous project and paste it in the new project folder.

2) Change the project name, repository link and other options  from the file if u want.

You can ignore the nextstep if you want all the packages

3)Then, remove the names of the packages that you don't want for the new project.

Then run `npm install` in command prompt.

This will install all the packages from previous project.